# Rss feed items get pulled in several times

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, rss, feed

I'm having a problem pulling in a RSS feed in my phonegap application. The code works and the feed gets pulled in correctly, but each item is displayed 3 times. What am I doing wrong here?

```
function getEvents() {
    showLoading();
    $.getFeed({
        url: 'http://thisismyfeedurl.com',
        success: function(feed) {
            var html = '';
            for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length; i++) {
                var item = feed.items[i];
                html += '<li><p><a class="title" href="#">' + item.title + '</a>' + item.description + '</p></li>';
                $('#eventscount').text(i);
            }
            $('#eventsfeed').append(html);
            hideLoading();
            $('object').show();
        }    
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. It works fine. Ps, comics.xml is http://www.reddit.com/r/comics.xml

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.github.com/jfhovinne/jFeed/master/build/dist/jquery.jfeed.js"></script>

<div id="eventscount"></div>
<div id="eventsfeed"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getFeed({
                    url: 'comics.xml',
                    success: function(feed) {
                            var html = '';
                            for(var i = 0; i < feed.items.length; i++) {
                                    var item = feed.items[i];
                                    html += '<li><p><a class="title" href="#">' + item.title + '</a>' + item.description + '</p></li>';
                                    $('#eventscount').text(i);
                            }
                            $('#eventsfeed').append(html);
                    }    
            });
    });
</script>
```

> 24
>
> Money in Sight!submitted by imasif [link] [11 comments]
>
> From my sketchbook: Evolutionary stages of Redditsubmitted by
>   Schaafwond [link] [55 comments]
>
> Basically, every sports column I read on Monday...submitted by milk4dh
>   [link] [21 comments]

(snip)

Comment: Hmm... must be something else causing it then, any one tried in phonegap? In the emulator and on the phone it pulls in the items and then when it comes to about item number 10 it starts over again on item 0. Same happens on item 20 etc.